# Rehabbing stubborn tendonosis

Tags: injury, recovery, tendons, rehabilitation

I've had tricep tendonosis for over 4 years.

I've seen numerous physios and put countless hours of my own research into it. Most of my rehab efforts have been with slow tempo / eccentric exercises.

I can feel them working but I always have some form of setback, and whenever I have a setback I struggle to get back on the right track. I find that a setback will often cost me a matter of months, which is why I can't ever make a full recovery.

Recently I've been trying a daily routine of 3x15 eccentric tricep extensions using Therabands (very light Therabands for that matter).

The way it often seems to work is like this:

1. Use a lighter weight due to pain
2. Go about 4 days of rehab exercises without pain
3. Pain starts to kick in when doing the exercises
4. Attempt at a lighter weight
5. 3-4 days of no pain during rehab exercises
6. Pain kicks in
7. Repeat

One physio did pick up on the fact that my scapula is winging a bit, so he gave me some exercises for this. But I don't feel that has made a huge amount of difference.

I've also started eating cleaner as I feel my diet might have been preventing me from healing properly.

Might it be an idea to take a few days off from my rehab exercises? I've heard very mixed opinions on how regularly to do eccentric exercises (most sources say to do them every day)

Comment: I had a similar sounding problem in my wrist and it turned out my tendon had adhered to something during the healing process which kept the eccentric exercises from lengthening the tendon.  My chiropractor was able to break the adhesion and full healing was quick after that. Good luck

Comment: @michael interesting! thanks, hopefully it's a similar thing with me. I'm going to see another physio soon as I feel like there has to be something interfering with it

Comment: When I started squatting my knees gave me a lot of issues and I got some knee sleeves. They just keep my knees warm throughout the workout. I don't know about tricep tendonitis but maybe ask your physiotherapist about elbow sleeves. They might help during the rehab process.

Comment: @C.Lange thanks, could be an idea! I have read that warming the area is a way to increase blood flow and therefore healing

Comment: @michael saw a new physio today and he gave me acupuncture... feels like it may have helped a bit! although it's way too early to tell I think